# Google Analytics get same domain referrals count

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I've got a site e.g example.com and I have this php file at example.com/redirect.php which just redirects to example.com. I also have Google Analytics on example.com but I don't have it on example.com/redirect.php So my question is - is there way to figure out how many people have come from example.com/redirect.php?

Comment: No I guess as It will redirect before any google js will load to keep track if that page hit. But alternative you can do it manually putting code in your `redirect.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that because you used the `php` tag that you are using the php `header` function to change location for your redirect. That being the case then you would not be able to have any javascript google analytics code happen before your redirect.

You could redirect to example.com?r=1 (or any other `$_GET` value). I believe that Google will record the difference.

Comment: Your assumption is right I am using header('location: example.com') to redirect